# How to store a python ndarray on disk?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, storage, gpu

I have a pkl file containing an ndarray that I originally dump using a GPU. I unpickle it with the GPU and now I want to store it as whatever, that I can later uncompress using a CPU. I run everything on a supercomputer and later I want to just have access to the ndarrays on a normal computer without a fancy GPU. I looked into functions such as

```
np.save()
np.savez()
```

but `save()` I can't set `allow_pickle=False` and when I load the array stored with `savez()` it's empty.

This is how I save things:

I run `THEANO_FLAGS="device=gpu,floatX=float32" srun -u python deep_q_rl/unpicklestuff.py`

unpicklestuff.py:

```
import sys 
import cPickle
import lasagne.layers
import os
import numpy as np

for i in os.listdir(path):
    net_file = open(path+str(i), 'r')
    network = cPickle.load(net_file)
    q_layers = lasagne.layers.get_all_layers(network.l_out)
    np.savez(savepath+str(i), q_layers)
```

And this is how I load them later:

```
q_layers = np.load(path)
```

Comment: Why do you need `allow_pickle=False`?

Comment: If I let it be true then I need a GPU to load it again.

Comment: Whats the `dtype` of the array?

Comment: the `dtype` is `float32`